# Hide a div when another is empty

Tags: scripting, blogspot

its my fisrt question, cause i dont find a answer in the search...

Its possible to hide a div, when another is empty? Here is the case:

```
<div id='TwitterTrackbacksWrapper'>
<h4><img align='bottom' alt='Twitter Trackbacks' src='http://Imagens/twitter-bird.png'/> twitter trackbacks</h4>
<div class='twitter-trackbacks' id='twitter-trackbacks'/>
</div>
```

I want to hide/remove the whole  Div ID TwitterTrackbacksWrapper when there is nothing to show on a div/class twitter-trackbacks. That is possible?

Answer (score 1):

On your `onload` of the page, check the `twitter-trackbacks` div's `innerHtml` property. If empty. set the style property of the TwitterTrackbacksWrapper to `display:'none'`.

Something like:

```
function hideIfEmpty()
{
  var inner = document.getElementById("twitter-trackbacks");
  if (inner.innerHTML=="")
    document.getElementById("TwitterTrackbacksWrapper").style="display:none;";
}
```

Comment: It must be in JQuery. Dont know why, this JavaScript doesnt work... But Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Sure, when you populate the data for the "twitter-trackbacks" area, if its empty, set the style of the TwitterTrackbacksWrapper to display: none.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works using JQuery.

```
if ($('#TwitterTrackbacksWrapper').html().length == 0) {
    //Then, there is nothing in the div 
    //Please remove me.
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Almost... Dont understand what i need to put in the commented area. I really needs a condition, using JQuery. If the DIV ID twitter-trackbacks was empty, so dont show the whole TwitterTrackbacksWrapper DIv ID...